# How to copy RedisToGo database in Heroku to local machine?

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis, redistogo

I have a node.js app, using RedisToGo and running in Heroku. I would like to copy the Redis To Go database to localhost for testing.

When developing Ruby on Rails app, I can use `heroku db:pull` command. Is there any similiar command which I can use for node.js and Redis?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There **was** a guide available from the redistogo support knowledge base but it got deleted, I used the way back machine to grab it's content and made a gist: https://gist.github.com/mmcdaris/29cfe920c846ae6dd5c6eb354c9abdd2
Same result different method.

Comment: Unfortunately that link is dead :(

Comment: Updated! @odlp I used the way back machine to grab the content and made a gist of it.

Answer (score 4):

You can slave your local instance of Redis to the RedisToGo instance - http://redistogo.com/documentation/exporting

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps I took to create local backup of a Heroku Redis instance, but this should be valid for other providers like RedisToGo and RedisCloud.

On the machine where you'd like to make the backup, jump to the redis CLI:

```
redis-cli
```

### Password?

If your master Redis DB (the one you want to replicate) has a password:

```
config set masterauth <password>
```

### Start replication

Run the following to begin replication:

```
SLAVEOF <host> <port>
```

To check the replication is underway run:

```
INFO replication
```

And you should see something like this:

```
# Replication
role:slave
master_host:some-host.compute-1.amazonaws.com
master_port:6519
master_link_status:up
master_last_io_seconds_ago:3
master_sync_in_progress:0
slave_repl_offset:35492914
slave_priority:100
slave_read_only:1
connected_slaves:0
master_repl_offset:0
repl_backlog_active:0
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:0
repl_backlog_histlen:0
```

Note the `master_link_status` should be `up`.

### Checking sync progress

When the sync is complete, the `INFO replication` should show:

```
master_sync_in_progress:0
```

To sense check the dataset has been synced you could compare the size of the database:

```
DBSIZE
```

### Saving a data dump to disk

Given the number of keys in the follower & master DB match, then save the DB to disk:

```
BGSAVE
CONFIG GET dir
```

And you should find the `dump.rdb` listed by the config command.

### Halting replication

Finally, you can stop replication with:

```
SLAVEOF NO ONE
```

---

Reference: [Redis replication guide](https://redis.io/topics/replication)